# Iterate list contents and find json files

Tags: python, python-3.x

Kind of breaking my head to find an elegant solution for the below scenario.

A list has directory structure, as its contents & need to find whether `request.json` or `response.json` is available in the `result` folder of the directory structure or one level below the result folder, called - `scheduler`.

Let's say:

```
input_paths = ['/root/services/builds/tesla', '/root/services/builds/google/apis', '/root/services/builds/qa/tests', '/root/services/builds/airlines_Solutions', '/root/services/builds/traffic_patterns/api']
```

Output should be:

```
/root/services/builds/tesla/result/request.json

/root/services/builds/google/apis/result/scheduler/request.json

/root/services/builds/qa/tests/result/scheduler/response.json
```

My code has multiple for loops that has os.walk and globs and looks pathetic. Looking forward to learn and understand a simple solution. Thanks.

Comment: What is the code you are calling _'pathetic'_?

Comment: check this it may helps you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3964681/find-all-files-in-a-directory-with-extension-txt-in-python?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply use `os.exists`

```
import os

for i in input_paths:
    if os.path.exists(os.path.join(i, "result/request.json")):
        print(os.path.join(i, "result/request.json"))

    elif os.path.exists(os.path.join(i, "result/scheduler/request.json")):
        print(os.path.join(i, "result/scheduler/request.json"))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot !! I did over complicate the work,  being a newbie.

Answer (score 1):

To recursively find all `request.json` or `response.json` in all you `input_paths` you could do:

```py
import os

file_name_pattern = ['request.json', 'response.json', ]
for path in input_paths:
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        for name in files:
            if name in file_name_pattern:
                print(os.path.join(root, name))
```

If the directory structure is mandatory to your findings you should add another filter for `dirs`.

The [answer of sushanth](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69032124/6644390) might be more efficient due to prevent the algorithm to search recursively but it might be a hassle to configure the code if more search locations become relevant.

Comment: @thrandt : Appreciate your inputs and solution provided, thanks!